# How to divide the water flow into pipes with equal flow each from a free surface?

Tags: hydraulics

From a free surface pond, I'd like to divide the outflow into two separate pipes and direct them in two different places. Each outflow has to be equal.
Do you have an idea ?

Comment: A Vee channel is good at converting a water level into a specific flow rate. If you have two such channels with the same water level, the flow should be fairly equal.

Comment: Hi @DaveTweed, thanks for you answer. Can you send me a description/picture of vee channels like this? thanks